# Get a value of span tag HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my span tag looks like this:

```
<span id="quantity_value" value="1">1</span>
```

And the value changes by using jquery.

I want to have value of this span as a parameter, when i try with js script:

```
var number = document.getElementById("quantity_value");
```

My number is equal to:

```
'<span id="quantity_value" value="1">1</span>'
```

But I want number to be equal to value.

Comment: With jquery you can say `$('#quantity_value').val()` to get the value of the span..
The first part is the selector which selects your span element. The .val() is a method to get the value of the attribute value.

Comment: `var number = document.getElementById("quantity_value").textContent` (vanilla JS) or `var number = document.getElementById("quantity_value").text();` (jQuery)

Comment: Actually since it's a span, having a value doesn't make sense here.  Spans are not input elements.

Comment: wait, what exactly the OP wanted? The text content inside element, or the value attribute of span?

Comment: "*And the value changes by using jquery.*"  Please explain this more

Comment: @Smankusors I want to redirect on page ('/../number') but when i pass 
var number = document.getElementById("quantity_value").innerHTML;
its static, my number is equal to 1 even if its changed

Comment: @Taplar i have jquery script, when i click + i add 1 to value and innerhtml and if i click - i remove 1 from value and innerhtml

Comment: @Taplar you said that span doesnt have value, so can i make input element invisible?

Comment: You could (`<input type="hidden">`), or you could use a data attribute.  Take a look at my answer below for an example using data attributes.  @Sebqu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
var number = document.getElementById("quantity_value").innerHTML;
```

By writing only

```
var number = document.getElementById("quantity_value");
```

you store object in variable.

Comment: I'd probably recommend naming the variable `quantityValue` or something for some added self documenting.  `number` is a small typo away from `Number` and potentially causing bigger issues. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you add:

`console.log(number);` just after you define it, and look at the debugger, you'll see it has various properties.

You want to get the `innerHTML`, property:

```
number.innerHTML
```

Comment: There is problem with it. It static i mean when i change html number.innerHTML is not changing

Comment: The variable is read at time of execution. It is not bound to the element. So if the element changes, the variable will have the same value. You need to re-read the value after the change, or bind an event to the element that will automatically update the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing `value` to a data field to fix your non-standards compliant html, and then you can retrieve that attribute when you need the value.  For instance:

```js
$('#changeValue').on('click', function(){
  var newValue = Date.now() % 100;
  
                                   //change the data attribute
  $('#quantity_value').text(newValue).data('value', newValue);
});

$('#getValue').on('click', function(){
  console.log($('#quantity_value').data('value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="quantity_value" data-value="1">1</span>
<div><button id="changeValue">Change Value</button></div>
<div><button id="getValue">Get Value</button></div>
```

Comment: i totally dont understand how it works.
I guess 
$('#changeValue'). is only for testing, am i right

if yes then why 
<span id="quantity_value" data-value="1">1</span>
doesnt have value

Comment: Yes, the buttons are just there for testing.  As stated in the comments to your question, `value` is not a valid attribute for `span` elements, as defined by the HTML web standard.  As such, this answer uses a data attribute, `data-value`, in the place of the value you were trying to use.  Data attributes can be on pretty much any element, and you can use the jQuery method `data()` to get/set the value of it.